# Draw waveform in NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opengl, animation, nsview

I need to draw a waveform in an NSView. (I have all the samples in an array). The drawing must be efficient and really fast without clipping, flickering, etc, it must be smooth. The waveform will be "moving" according to the song position and some changes to the samples (DSP processing) will be shown as visual representation onto NSView in realtime.

I'm familiar drawing lines, arcs, etc onto canvas objects and I have developed apps doing such things but not on Mac OS X ...

I want to ask if anyone can guide me where to start drawing! Core Animation, OpenGL, simple override drawing methods, ??, etc. Which would be the best practice - API to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would keep it simple and create an `NSView` subclass with an `audioData` property that uses Cocoa drawing. You could call `[view setAudioData:waveArray]` which would in turn call `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]`.

In your `drawRect:` method you could then iterate through the samples and use `NSRectFill()` accordingly. Here `sample`'s `value` is between 0 and 1.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [[NSColor blueColor]set];
    for (id sample in self.waveArray) {
        NSRect drawingRect = NSZeroRect;
        drawingRect.origin.x = [self bounds].origin.x;
        drawingRect.origin.y = [self bounds].origin.y + ([self.waveArray indexOfObject:sample]/([self.waveArray count] - 1.0));
        drawingRect.size.width = [self bounds].size.width/[self.waveArray count];
        drawingRect.size.height = [self bounds].size.height * [sample value];
        NSRectFill(drawingRect);
    }
}
```

This code isn't exact, and you should be sure to make it more efficent by only drawing samples inside `dirtyRect`.

Comment: You say that -(void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect is being called partially for a specific rect of the control too? Any way... since [view setAudioData] will force the entire control to be redrawn, (due to new wave data) maybe it doesn't matter so much !? or does it?

Comment: `-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect` is called at will by Cocoa (and should never be called directly) and it is possible that only part of the view will need to be redrawn (if it is in a scroll view, for example). For efficiency's sake, you should only redraw what needs to be redrawn, rather than the entire view. `setNeedsDisplay:YES` (which should be called inside `setAudioData:`) tells the view to redraw completely. The [Cocoa View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/) would be some good reading.

Comment: oh Thank you very much, no need to though, for the time being. If I need sth I definitely contact! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a really long and thin image to represent a single bar/column for the waveform.

My plan would be to have a NSTimer that moves all bars of the wave one to the left every 0.01 seconds.

So something like this in the loop.

```
for (int x; x < [WaveArray count] ; x++)
{
    UIImageView * Bar = [WaveArray ObjectAtIndex: x];
    [Bar setCenter:CGPointMake(Bar.center.x-1,Bar.center.y)];
}
```

Now all you have to do is create the objects at the correct hight and add them to the WaveArray and they all will be moved to the left.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My issue is whether to override drawing methods of NSView to do all the things you mention or use OpenGL, Quartz, just the AppKit, etc. I'm familirial with the technic to use but not at all with which APIs to use.

Comment: I actually ment to do this all from a view controller haha.

Comment: I wouldn't even have a custom view

Comment: Xmm, I need something more efficient... I think :)

Comment: (1) UIImageView doesn't exist on Mac OS X, and (2) why would you do all drawing in a view controller instead of a view?